# WP: AesManaged encryption vs. mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php, windows-phone-7, encryption, aes

I'm trying to synchronize my encryption and decryption methods between C# and PHP but something seems to be going wrong.

In the Windows Phone 7 SDK you can use AESManaged to encrypt your data

I use the following method:

```
    public static string EncryptA(string dataToEncrypt, string password, string salt)
    {
        AesManaged aes = null;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;

        try
        {
            //Generate a Key based on a Password, Salt and HMACSHA1 pseudo-random number generator 
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt));

            //Create AES algorithm with 256 bit key and 128-bit block size 
            aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);

            // to check my results against those of PHP
            var blaat1 = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key);
            var blaat2 = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV);

            //Create Memory and Crypto Streams 
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            //Encrypt Data 
            byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(dataToEncrypt);
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            //Return Base 64 String 
            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());

            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cryptoStream != null)
                cryptoStream.Close();

            if (memoryStream != null)
                memoryStream.Close();

            if (aes != null)
                aes.Clear();
        }
    }
```

I solved the problem of generating the Key. The Key and IV are similar as those on the PHP end. But then the final step in the encryption is going wrong.

here is my PHP code

```
<?php

function pbkdf2($p, $s, $c, $dk_len, $algo = 'sha1') {

    // experimentally determine h_len for the algorithm in question
     static $lengths;
     if (!isset($lengths[$algo])) { $lengths[$algo] = strlen(hash($algo, null, true)); }
    $h_len = $lengths[$algo];

    if ($dk_len > (pow(2, 32) - 1) * $h_len) {
         return false; // derived key is too long
     } else {
         $l = ceil($dk_len / $h_len); // number of derived key blocks to compute
         $t = null;
         for ($i = 1; $i <= $l; $i++) {
             $f = $u = hash_hmac($algo, $s . pack('N', $i), $p, true); // first iterate
             for ($j = 1; $j < $c; $j++) {
                 $f ^= ($u = hash_hmac($algo, $u, $p, true)); // xor each iterate
             }
             $t .= $f; // concatenate blocks of the derived key
         }
         return substr($t, 0, $dk_len); // return the derived key of correct length
     }

}


$password = 'test';
$salt = 'saltsalt';
$text = "texttoencrypt";

#$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
#echo $iv_size . '<br/>';
#$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
#print_r (mcrypt_list_algorithms());

$iv = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";

$key = pbkdf2($password, $salt, 1000, 32);
echo 'key: ' . base64_encode($key) . '<br/>';
echo 'iv: ' . base64_encode($iv) . '<br/>';

echo '<br/><br/>';

function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 32){
     $len = strlen($string);
     $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
     $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
     return $string;
 }

echo 'text: ' . $text . '<br/>';
echo 'text: ' . addpadding($text) . '<br/>';

// -- works till here

$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo '1.' . $crypttext . '<br/>';
$crypttext = base64_encode($crypttext);
echo '2.' . $crypttext . '<br/>';

$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, addpadding($text), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo '1.' . $crypttext . '<br/>';
$crypttext = base64_encode($crypttext);
echo '2.' . $crypttext . '<br/>';

?>
```

So to point out, the Key and IV look similar on both .NET and PHP, but something seems to be going wrong in the final call when executing mcrypt_encrypt(). The end result, the encrypted string, differs from .NET.

Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong. As far as i can see everything should be correct.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Additional information on the AESManaged object in .NET

Keysize = 256
Mode = CBC
Padding = PKCS7

Comment: What does *seems to be going wrong* mean? Do you get error messages? Do you get different results? (This is normal, if the IV is random.) Can't you decrypt again? anything else?

Comment: Hi Paulo, the end result, the encrypted string, differs between PHP and .NET, but i'm almost certain i'm inputting the correct Key and IV (and text to encrypt). Hope that explains it a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problems. You need to make sure you use UTF8 Encoding on the strings and you are using the correct padding (PKCS7)

Here is the code:

```
    public static string EncryptA(string dataToEncrypt, string password, string salt)
    {
        AesManaged aes = null;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;

        try
        {
            //Generate a Key based on a Password, Salt and HMACSHA1 pseudo-random number generator 
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt));

            //Create AES algorithm with 256 bit key and 128-bit block size 
            aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"); // new byte[] { 0x41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);

            //Create Memory and Crypto Streams 
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            //Encrypt Data 
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToEncrypt);
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            //Return Base 64 String 
            var temp = memoryStream.ToArray();
            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(temp);

            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cryptoStream != null)
                cryptoStream.Close();

            if (memoryStream != null)
                memoryStream.Close();

            if (aes != null)
                aes.Clear();
        }
    }
```

and in php:

```
<?php
function pbkdf2($p, $s, $c, $dk_len, $algo = 'sha1') {

    // experimentally determine h_len for the algorithm in question
     static $lengths;
     if (!isset($lengths[$algo])) { $lengths[$algo] = strlen(hash($algo, null, true)); }
    $h_len = $lengths[$algo];

    if ($dk_len > (pow(2, 32) - 1) * $h_len) {
         return false; // derived key is too long
     } else {
         $l = ceil($dk_len / $h_len); // number of derived key blocks to compute
         $t = null;
         for ($i = 1; $i <= $l; $i++) {
             $f = $u = hash_hmac($algo, $s . pack('N', $i), $p, true); // first iterate
             for ($j = 1; $j < $c; $j++) {
                 $f ^= ($u = hash_hmac($algo, $u, $p, true)); // xor each iterate
             }
             $t .= $f; // concatenate blocks of the derived key
         }
         return substr($t, 0, $dk_len); // return the derived key of correct length
     }
}

$text = "blaat";
$password = 'this is my secret passwordthis is my secret password';
$salt = 'thisismysalt';

#$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
#$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

$iv = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';

$key = pbkdf2($password, $salt, 1000, 32);
echo 'key size: ' . strlen($key) . '<br/>';
echo 'key: ' . base64_encode($key) . '<br/>';
echo 'iv size: ' . strlen($iv) . '<br/>';
#echo 'iv: ' . $iv . '<br/>';
echo 'iv: ' . base64_encode($iv) . '<br/>';

echo '<br/><br/>';

#    $data = $this->paddingAlgorithm->padData($data, $blockSize);
#    return $iv . mcrypt_encrypt($this->MCRYPT_DES, $keyBytes, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

function addpadding($string)
{
     $blocksize = 16;
     $len = strlen($string);
     $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
     $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

     return $string;
}

$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, addpadding($text), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$crypttext = base64_encode($crypttext);
echo '3. [' . $crypttext . ']<br/>';

echo '<br/>';

?>
```

Hope this will help somebody as well.

Paulo thanks for your help!

Comment: When i integrate encryption using this function i g0t two different values from c# and php . I look around all fields like key, salt etc,All are same. if any thing missing from above C# code. If you can help me please help me.

Comment: Hi Deepu, this code is complete and has been used for a program. You will need to provide your sourcecode and an example of the data if you want anybody to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is the version of the Rijndael algorithm with block size 256 bits, while AES is only the versions with block size 128 bits. These are not compatible.

Use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`, to get an algorithm which is equivalent to AES. It still supports all three key sizes standardized as AES, i.e. 128 bits (16 bytes), 196 bits (24 bytes) and 256 bits (32 bytes). Simply pass a long enough string as key.

Comment: I switched to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 and my key size is 32bits. The keys same to match between .NET and PHP, but the final result of mcrypt_encrypt still doesn't match the end result of the encryption on .NET. 

I'm using the following input: 
$text = "this is my text"; 
$password = 'this is my secret passwordthis is my secret password';
$salt = 'thisismysalt';

the base64_encode strings of the IV and KEY look similar on both systems. Any other idea what can be going wrong?

thank you for your time!

Comment: "look similar", or "are identical"?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the 256-bit version on the .NET side? I don't see anything in your code that sets the key size (and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) says nothing about the default value).

Comment: They key and IV are identical on both systems. I updated the post (bottom) with details on the AESManaged object on .NET.

Comment: One more idea: fix the block size for your PHP addpadding function, it should be 16, not 32.

Comment: Did that, didn't help. I'm not well versed in encryption but it seems that the .NET result is longer then the PHP result when encoded to base64. the .NET result is 44 characters, one of the PHP result is 25, the other is 24. could this be related to the Keysize, etc ?   EDIT: the length matches when using RIJNDAEL_256 in PHP.

Comment: It seems that adjusting the IV doesn't change the encrypted string in PHP. That seems wrong to me. I will investigate.

Comment: Your 24 characters output corresponds to one block (128 bits), the 44 character one to two blocks (256 bits). 25 characters shouldn't ever occur. Sorry, I have no ideas anymore ... have to go to bed.