# Windows Phone: How to encrypt/decrypt using AesManaged class on Windows Phone

Tags: encryption, windows-phone-8

How to Encrypt/Decrypt byte array using AesManaged class in Windows Phone 8? I'm trying to encrypt 16 bit data, but observed that after encryption the data size is getting changed to 256bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Padding (you can't turn it off) and Aes is a block cipher with 128bits blocks. You can see some example usage here: [real aes sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116133/wp-aesmanaged-encryption-vs-mcrypt-encrypt)

Comment: Can you please provide some reference which shows the decryption using AesManaged class.I'm getting problem during decryption.